# Could an emulation of Bluetooth Keyboard on a smartphone be made to access the Microsoft Bluetooth Keyboard driver of Windows 10?

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

As I was searching for means to connect a Bluetooth Keyboard to windows 10 It seemed that I just need to pair the keyboard to the notebook by selecting the Microsoft proper Bluetooth driver.
When I searched the emulation of a Bluetooth Keyboard on an Android device I found that to interface it to Windows 10 there is a need for a piece of SW they call "server".
I wonder if there is a real need for it and if there is a way to use the Microsoft driver to work with the emulation of the Bluetooth Keyboard.

Comment: Bluetooth usually works different, devices implement standardized profiles such as HID (keyboard/mouse) so that no special driver is needed as long as the profile is supported. On Windows I assume the software is mostly needed for nice GUI programs for additional functions but the keyboard itself should work using the default HID profile.